# How to get UpsertResult when using Mongo Outbound channel adapter?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration to store data in a mongo database. I'm using the java classes (MongoDbStoringMessageHandler), not the xml configuration and I can't find the way to get the results when adding some data in the database...

Is it possible ? How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MongoDbStoringMessageHandler` is a one-way component and it doesn't return anything.

Consider to use a `MongoDbOutboundGateway` instead with the `CollectionCallback` injected where you can perform an `updateMany()` and get `UpdateResult` as a reply from this gateway.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-outbound-gateway

**UPDATE**

> but I don't know what parameter to put for the function to insert the Message payload.... Since there is no reference of the message in the ServiceActivator

Oh! I see. That a bug. We can't get access to the message from that context. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/projects/INT/

Meanwhile as a workaround I suggest you ti write a custom POJO with injected `MongoOperations` and ther you can build any possible logic against a `requestMessage`.

The JIRA is here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4570

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution right now but I don't know how to specify the data I have to insert in the db. I'm using the method `gateway.setCollectionCallback(collection -> { collection.insertOne()});` but I don't know what parameter to put for the function to insert the Message payload.... Since there is no reference of the message in the ServiceActivator

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, though I don't quite understand the utility of the class ! I'll write my own POJO and hope it'll be efficient.

Comment: Good. I've raised a JIRA on the matter by myself.